# ArcGIS 10.1: Do I need to deauthorize licences when reinstalling Licence manager on the same PC?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-server, license

I have installed ArcGIS Desktop 10.1 Advanced concurrent use and Licence server administrator on the same PC (Windows 7 Ultimate, 32 bit). I would like to reinstall the whole installation of ArcGIS: the Desktop and the Licence server administrator.

Do I need to deauthorize my Licences before the reinstallation of Licence server administrator, if I am using the same PC?

The deauthorization of Licence server administrator from one PC to another is allowed 4 times per year; what is the rule for the same PC/reinstalled Windows?

I don't want to just try to reinstall Licence server because I am afraid to lose my licences.

I have no longer paid customer support from ESRI to ask them directly.

Comment: This is really a question for Esri Customer Service.

Comment: I sent my email to ESRI, so maybe they will contact me even I'm off the paid support.